# Node basic auth with loading credentials from Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, basic-authentication

I am using NodeJs on server and I need to add some basic auth function, which asks the user for the credentials before any file (like html or js files) is downloaded to the user's browser. When I tried to view the cource code when I am not log in, I can't be able to access it like in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brwSs.jpg).
This works fine with `basic-auth` module, but only for one username and password.

```
app.use(basicAuth('username', 'password'));
```

And there is the problem - I need to load this credentions from Database and check if the user is admin and compare his encrypted password.
I tryed this:

```
// ****
var basicAuth = require('basic-auth');
// ****
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  var user = basicAuth(req);
  if (user) {
      var c = mysql.createConnection(db);
      var q = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '" + user.name + "' AND admin = 1;";
      c.query(q, function (error, result) {
          c.end();
          if (error) {
              console.log(error);
              res.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="example"');
              return res.status(401).send();
          } else {
              if (result.length === 1 &&
                  bcrypt.compareSync(user.pass, result[0].password)) {

                  return next();
              } else {
                  res.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="example"');
                  return res.status(401).send();
              }
          }
      });
  } else {
      res.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="example"');
      return res.status(401).send();
  }
});
```

This works fine, but this function is called every time, when the browser communicates with the server, which is about 70 times on loading simple page (It is not asking the user for the credentials again, "only" run this function). This function **lasts about 200ms** on every request (because of the query and password comparing), in sum the loading lasts about **15 seconds**, which is **not acceptable.**

Can you someone please help me, how to figured out this problem or recommend me some other NodeJs library, which can help me with that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So if you store you hash in the DB and the Admin Flag in your DB, why don't you do the following Select request :

```
var q = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '" + user.name + "' AND password = '" + bcrypt.hashSync(user.pass) + "' AND admin = '1';";
```

If you get only one result it is OK, otherwise it is refused...

Comment: Thats not so easy, you must compare the password with the hash only using `bcrypt.compareSync(user.pass, hash)`, your metod is not working. However this will not solve the problem because this will not much speed up the page when loading....

Comment: Hum... If you reduce the 200ms that may help. but I forgotten about the salt, agreed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, every request to the server is running your authentication, causing page loads to be slow. I don't understand how someone can log in if all the routes are behind the basic auth check you are doing, but that is besides the point.

The way I set my node apps up are to create an array of functions for auth and pass these in to the specific routes where I require authentication, this way it is being run for each resource I may be serving. For example(psuedocode-ish):

```
// this is the authentication function array, each function in the array
// will be run when this array is called on a route, require next()
// after successful auth to continue on through the array/route handlers

// for your example, adminAuth would be the anonymous 
// function in your app.use method
var auth = [adminAuth];

// some random route examples

// this is an unprotected route
app.get('/login', loginHandler);

// these are protected routes and will have auth called
app.get('/api/users', auth, getUserHandler);
app.post('/api/user', auth, postUserHandler);
```

So in conclusion, you can put the auth call only on protected resources, this way images, html, js, css, etc can be served without running the auth check everytime.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.  I recognize that you need to do the password check every request, but you don't necessarily need to hit the database every time.  Assuming that you *must* do HTTP Basic (not recommended anymore, and I hope if you are, that you're doing it over HTTPS), then one major improvement you can make is if you create some kind of fast data cache.  The easiest form of this would be in-memory (assuming you're OK with each instance of your app keeping its own copy), but you could also use something like memcached or redis for it instead depending on your use case.

A really trivial implementation would be just keeping an in-memory JS object with a key equal to the username and the value equal to the data returned from the db. Something like:

```
var userCache = {}; // something local to the module is the easiest way
```

Then, when you are going to query the db, you just check the `userCache` first:

```
if(userCache[user.name]) // check password
else
 // do your query and insert a successful result into the userCache for later.
```

Just doing that should significantly reduce your response times per resource, though again for a production solution you'll probably want multi-tier caching (e.g. an in-memory cache and a redis or memcached cache to help performance across multiple instances of your app).

Second, you should use the callback version of the bcrypt check.  It won't be faster on a given request, but it may give your application more overall request capacity, which should help.

Third, your actual SQL query is a bad idea for three reasons.  First, in most databases, you'll have worse performance for using a `SELECT *` vs selecting the specific fields you want.  This is both on the DB side (query cache optimization) as well as on the Node side (time to deal with fields getting converted / cast between a string response and a JS object for example).  Second, the string concatenation you're doing is an invitation for [SQL Injection attacks](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/).  Look into using parameterized queries instead.  Lastly, if you know your users will be unique, you should also add a `LIMIT 1` to the query, since you're only expecting one result and again the DB can do some optimization around that.